# Redirection from www to non-www doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web, redirect

I am trying to set a redirection from www to non-www page. I found plenty of instruction but I am missing something. Tracerout from www and non-www is identical and it's hitting my server so the DNS is save.

Here is my apache2 conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mypage.com
    ServerAlias www.mypage.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mypage

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mypage>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

and here is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone see what am I missing?

Comment: One of the two initial rewrite rules will get applied, so your redirection rules can never get matched. You need to reverse the order. The rules are processed from top to bottom...

Comment: The question however is why you do such things in a dynamic configuration file, since you apparently have control over the real host configuration. You definitely should consider moving your rewriting / redirection logic into the real host configuration. Dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") have a lot of disadvantages...

Answer (score 0):

The reason your rule redirecting www to non-www probably isn't working is because it occurs after other rules with the `L` flag (which of course means to stop processing the rewrite rules). You might consider the following configuration, which puts that particular part first:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want to note a couple things here.

- The `RewriteBase` directive is kind of unnecessary here, unless that htaccess file isn't in the document root.
- The `RewriteRule` for non-www can use the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable, and simply rewrite the entire request.
- Assuming you meant to rewrite the entire URI to `/index.php`on the last rule, you'd use the `^` character for that.

Comment: Hiya, after applying these changes I am one step closer. If I go to www.mypage.com it redirects me to http://mypage.com%24%7Brequest_uri%7D

Comment: @onicniepytaj Sorry about that, there was a typo in the rule. It should be `%{REQUEST_URI}` not `${REQUEST_URI}` (notice the percent sign). Let me know if that works for you now.